# Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0 in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: .net, sql-server, dll, ssms

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to a server in SQL server management studio.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (mscorlib)

The System.EnterpriseServices.dll in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a folder has the following version:

[image: dll version number]

I tried so many things but no luck. Is there any way that I can specify in SQL server management studio to open the current version of the .dll in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3 without looking for Version=4.0.0.0 ?

Comment: Try to run SSMS as Administrator. If not work then it may be instalaltion issue.

Comment: Tried that too, still the same error

Comment: You can try to upgrade/downgrade ssms, that may sort the issue

Comment: I've got the same problem and no ideas for a solution so far.